# Tracking multiple clicks on the same element

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Looking for a way to track if an element has been clicked multiple times (for example, a user clicks "Submit" button several times to place an order).

We are doing some work redeveloping a website and in our UX research we found that people don't download PDFs from the site because the link behind the button is broken. We noticed that people tend to click the button several times before giving up, yet some still manage to download the PDF.

In order to show our changes to code have improved site performance and user experiences, we want to show that these "multiple clicks" have decreased.

Since the site uses Google Analytics, I have tried to create a variable in GTM that counts clicks on the same click element (which doesn't work):

```
function() {
var the_div = {{Click Element}};
var clickCount = 0;                      
return clickCount;                      
}
```

I expect the output to be a count of the times I've clicked on the Click Element (1, 2, 3, etc....)

Comment: Just to explain why this did not work, you declare your clickCount in the function scope, you set it to zero every time the function is called and you never actually  increment it (also you do not actually use your "the_div" variable).

Comment: The result that you want to achieve does not need any additional code. You need to send an event each time the user clicks on the button and after that you check in Analytics if the event that match that category/action/label fired per session decrease over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the delay in responding. 
We found a solution.

As Piertstorff pointed out, the variable sets clickCount to zero every time it is called. The solution, was to build a custom HTML tag (that runs JS) - not a variable - that fires on a Page Load Trigger and listens for multiple clicks within a 2-second timeframe. The HTML tag then passes an event to the DataLayer and stored in a variable.

That variable (signalling multiple clicks occurred) activates a trigger for another tag that passes the {{Click Classes}} variable to GA

Answer (score 0):

Use `javascript` variable with global scope

```
<script>
countClicks = 0;
    function clickCountFunction() {
         countClicks++;
    }
</script>
```

Add `onClick` attribute in button and call `clickCountFunction()` in it

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

Define a varable for count. and on each click increment it.

```js
var i = 1;
$('#elem').on('click',function(){
  console.log(i);
  i++;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elem">click here</div>
```